# Parse HTML Table how cell and rows with PHP

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

```
<?php

    include ("simpel_html_dom.php");
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML('http://www.arbworld.net/en/moneyway');

    $xpath = new \DomXPath($dom);

    // query the first column with class "value" of the table with class "attributes"
    $elements = $xpath->query('(/table[@class="grid"]//tr[@class="belowHeader"])');

    // iterate through all found td elements
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        echo $element->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```

I would to scrape the HTML table but when I run the code the result will be an empty page.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: unless I am mistaken `simpel_html_dom.php` is spelled incorrectly - it should, I think, be `simple_html_dom.php` ~ but why include that anyway if you use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`?

Answer (score 0):

That HTML is badly formed ( according to `libxml` ) so you need to account for that when loading the source data which, incidentally, you do either with `loadHTMLFile` to load a url or `loadHTML` to load a string of HTML.

```
$url='http://www.arbworld.net/en/moneyway';
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
libxml_clear_errors();


$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//table[@class="grid"]/tr[@class="belowHeader"]/td');

if( $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->textContent;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result will always be an empty page. Can you explain better to me?
I'm trying to understand better the section of Parsing and i would to focus it

Comment: the above works fine for me for testing. I cannot create a live demo on `http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/` sadly to show - but the response begins `Romanian Liga I22.Dec 18:00:00 FCSBUniversitat2.063.33.999.9 %€ 2070.1 %€ 00 %€ 0€ 207 22.Dec 18:00:00 Italian Serie A22.Dec 11:30:00 AtalantaAC Milan1.8844.499.7 %€ 21 5580.1 %€ 170.2 %€ 46€ 21 622 22.Dec 11:30:00 English League 221.Dec 15:00:00` and continues

Comment: Perfect it work! If i would tranform it on table, will I use HTML?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see it like in IMG and not in this way :

Romanian Liga I22.Dec 18:00:00 FCSBUniversitat2.063.33.999.9 %€ 2070.1 %€ 00 %€ 0€ 207 22.Dec 18:00:00 Italian Serie A22.Dec 11:30:00 AtalantaAC Milan1.8844.499.7 %€ 21 5580.1 %€ 170.2 %€ 46€ 21 622 22.Dec 11:30:00 English League 221.Dec 15:00:00

I would see it in columns and rows

[image]

Understand?